# polymorphic interface for a polymorphic class instance

Tags: c#

I have an IHasInventory interface that tells that the classes that inherits it got an Inventory.

I also got an IHasExtendedInventory the tell that those who inherit it has an ExtendedInventory with more features.

I want classes with an IHasExtendedInventory to have the same functionality as the base IHasInventory.

If a class inherits IHasSomeExtendedInventory, it would need two properties named Inventory of type Inventory and ExtendedInventory. How do a go about designing such a system?
Is it possible to have on entry Inventory, or do i need to rename one of the properties for it to work?

```
interface IHasInventory
{
    Inventory Inventory{get;}
}

interface IHasSomeExtendedInventory : IHasInventory
{
    ExtendedInventory Inventory{get;}
}

class Inventory 
{

}

class ExtendedInventory : Inventory 
{

}
```

EDIT:

my solution so far is the following, but I'm hoping for somehting a bit more clean

```
interface IHasSomeExtendedInventory : IHasInventory
{
    public ExtendedInventory ExtendedInventory => Inventory as ExtendedInventory;
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama 
Explicit Implementation is more or less the same as renaming one of the getters, as they don't have the singular access point that I want.

Comment: Why is it "more or less the same"? With an explicit interface implementation, both `IHasSomeExtendedInventory a;` and `IHasInventory b;` would allow you to access `a.Inventory` (an `ExtendedInventory`) and `b.Inventory` (a regular `Inventory`).

Comment: You can't have a single acccess point AND a safe typed system at the same time. The runtime can't decide if the returned value is of type Inventory or ExtendedInventory at compiletime. So you must give enough context this can be done. Either by naming, explicit interface implementation or giving up on types and returning just object and the caller has to deal with casting and interpreting.

Comment: I would need two properties a and b, I only want a single one 'a'. If a class with an 'a' have a regular inventory the 'a' would allow for the methods of the regular inventory . And if it inherits the extended one, 'a' would be able to call the regular and extended inventory methods.

Comment: @Ralf: sad, I was hoping there was a workaround. Thanks

Comment: Hmm. So are you looking to check if the class implements `IHasSomeExtendedInventory`, or do you not care about that and you're just looking to check if `Inventory`'s instance is an `ExtendedInventory`? I'm just trying to visualise your approach to actually using the extended inventory.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I was hoping the C# was smart enough to allow type extension to inherited types, since it wont give you a compile error if you inherit an interface from another one and both have a field/property/method of the same name

Comment: Looks like a job for generics to me. `IHasInventory<TInventory> where TInventory : IInventory`, with a `TInventory Inventory { get; }` member. No?

Comment: My point was that, unless you use generics, at some point you will need to check _something_ for your plan to work. You will either need to check if the object held in the `Inventory` property is actually an `ExtendedInventory`, or you will have to check if the type implements `IHasExtendedInventory`. Without doing one of these things you wouldn't be able to use the methods made available by `ExtendedInventory` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, than you can use something like this:

```
interface IHasInventory<T>
where T : Inventory
{
    T Inventory { get; }
}

interface IHasSomeExtendedInventory : IHasInventory<ExtendedInventory>
{
}
```